# Same html source code via two servers rendered differently

Tags: firefox, source

I am in the process of migrating my website from one host to another and noticed strange behavior:
Identical html page served from two different hosting servers render identical on Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Edge, but differently on Firefox depending on server. Both servers run apache. The difference is in size of font and size of images. Font sizes are specified in stylesheet as em.
Any idea as to the cause or remedy?

Comment: Do you or did you have a load balancer  in front of one of the webservers?  Maybe someone was injecting html code into the page while it was traversing the interwebs.  I should add that this is a long shot at being the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is upping their security and they are also in the process of moving some functionality out (Java, etc.), so it's understandable that things might not display correctly. If FF is having trouble understanding your website then maybe you can check out the view source code on the live page and see if it gives any errors? If not, the formatting may have to be changed or updated.

Comment: I use the W3C XHTML validator on pages from both servers and get a clean bill of health from each